# can run a task every X second with Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Hy guys, I have read the chapter called scheduling of Laravel's documentation, but 
I haven't found much information. I'm trying to customize the execution of a task to make it run every 30 seconds. Is there a solution ?
Sorry for my english and have a good day.

Answer (score 10):

By default CRON tasks are scheduled in minimal period 1 minute, but there is workaround for your issue.

In Console Kernel you should do something like this:

```php
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('your_command:run', ['--delay'=> 0])->everyMinute();
     $schedule->command('your_command:run', ['--delay'=> 30])->everyMinute();
}
```

In your Command class you should define the `$signature` variable that can take the delay parameter.

```php
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'your_command:run {--delay= : Number of seconds to delay command}';
```

In the handle method you should read value of this parameter and sleep this task for specific number of second using built-in `sleep()` function.

```php
/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    // code
    sleep(intval($this->option('delay')));
}
```

This solution will run your task every 30 seconds, you can multiply number of task with different delay. In this case you need to edit **schedule** method in Kernel class.

Answer (score -1):

I've got this quote on the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling)...

> In the past, developers have generated a Cron entry for each task they need to schedule. However, this is a headache. Your task schedule is no longer in source control, and you must SSH into your server to add the Cron entries. The Laravel command scheduler allows you to fluently and expressively define your command schedule within Laravel itself, and only a single Cron entry is needed on your server.

You still need to use Cron to run your tasks but using the Laravel's  Scheduling you set only one job on the Cron and control all the jobs of your application through the Task Scheduling.

**Example:**

Set this cron on your server:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run
```

It is gonna call the Laravel command scheduler every minute and then, Laravel evaluates your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

Then on your file **app/Console/Kernel.php** you can configure all your tasks as the code below:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
    })->daily();

$schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
```

Comment: This solution allow you to run a task every minutes, not every X seconds.
This is because the cron execution interval is once every minute, so you can't have intervals lower than that!